# How to detect which OS type the current guest is in the Vagrantfile

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I'd like to have one Vagrantfile for multiple different OS types (e.g. windows and linux). I'm currently attempting to do something like this:

```
...
if config.vm.guest.to_s == "windows"
    # ... do something windows specific
else
    # ... do something linux specific
end
```

However, `config.vm.guest` returns an `Object` instance, not a string or a symbol, even though it was set in the base box Vagrant file (i.e. `config.vm.guest = :windows`).

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you happen to figure this out?

Comment: no, I didn't. I added more logic in my code that is using vagrant so I know which type of OS it is `:^/`

Comment: And what was the "more logic"? Please share. I need to detect if os type is windows then do something which is not not required in case of other OS.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet you're trying to do this in a `~/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile`.  The problem is that `~/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile` is run *before* the `Vagrantfile` in your current directory.

So it cannot know anything about the configuration before hand.